# What about tag-bags or a tag-category in order to simplify favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

As a Stack Overflow user, I'm interested in a few subjects, for example `WMI`, `Active-Directory`, and `PowerShell`. But to follow these subjects on SO, I have to register to multiple tags. If I use `Active-Directory` as an example, when I want to answer questions around this subject, it concerns `Active-Directory`, `ADSI`, `ADAM`, `LDS` tags.

So I would find it useful to find along with favorite tags, favorite tag-bags. (Or tags-set?)

The behaviour of a tag-bag should be to show the recent questions about the tags that are present in the bag.

I understand that my tag-bags on one subject are not the same as another user's. It would be nice if each user can define up 3 or 4 bags.

Comment: So what's the tag bag used for exactly? _Just_ to see all questions within a group of tags?

Comment: Yes it will avoid to click multiple tags to see if it exits questions you can answer. I answer on `Powershell` tags, but it exists `PowerShellV1.0`, `PowerShellV2.0`, `PowerShellV3.0`, `PowerShellV4.0`, and for me these tags contains Powershell questions.

Comment: Will they have anything to do with asking a question? I'm wondering since you mention asking questions in this example

Comment: You can use wildcards in the favourite tag list. So you could simplify your Powershell-taglist to Powershell*

Comment: On my point of view tags-bags are not involved in asking questions, their object is to "group" tags around user subject.

Comment: Wildcard works for Powershell, but not for the example I give in the question.